# Embedded GML in XML to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr

Tags: geojson, convert, ogr2ogr, xml

I have an XML file that contains GML parts in it. I tried to use ogr2ogr without success to convert it to GeoJSON. I lose most of properties from the upper XML node.

The associated schema for the input file is https://schemas.wmo.int/iwxxm/1.1/iwxxm.xsd

My file looks like:

```
<collect:MeteorologicalBulletin xmlns:collect="http://def.wmo.int/collect/2014" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:iwxxm="http://icao.int/iwxxm/2023-1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" gml:id="uuid.9cfa8f87-0c98-4300-bac4-62be8d908334">
    <collect:meteorologicalInformation>
    <iwxxm:WAFSSignificantWeatherForecast reportStatus="NORMAL" permissibleUsage="OPERATIONAL"><gml:identifier codeSpace="http://wafs/sigwxfc">uuid.82d0b8e9-64d8-4b75-9c95-45b7538064ef</gml:identifier>

            <iwxxm:boundingPeriod>
                <gml:TimePeriod>
                    <gml:beginPosition>
                        2024-03-13T12:00:00Z
                    </gml:beginPosition>
                    <gml:endPosition>
                        2024-03-13T12:00:00Z
                    </gml:endPosition>
                </gml:TimePeriod>
            </iwxxm:boundingPeriod>

            <iwxxm:boundingVolume>
                <iwxxm:ElevatedEnvelope>
                    <gml:lowerCorner srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">-90 -180</gml:lowerCorner>
                    <gml:upperCorner srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">90 180</gml:upperCorner>
                    <iwxxm:upperElevation uom="FL">600</iwxxm:upperElevation>
                    <iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>STD</iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>
                    <iwxxm:lowerElevation uom="FL">100</iwxxm:lowerElevation>
                    <iwxxm:lowerVerticalReference>STD</iwxxm:lowerVerticalReference>
                </iwxxm:ElevatedEnvelope>
            </iwxxm:boundingVolume>

            <iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/TURBULENCE"/><iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/TROPOPAUSE"/><iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/JETSTREAM"/><iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/AIRFRAME_ICING"/><iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/CLOUD"/><iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/TROPICAL_CYCLONE"/><iwxxm:phenomenaList xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/VOLCANO"/><iwxxm:issueTime>
                <gml:TimeInstant>
                    <gml:timePosition>2024-03-13T11:45:58Z</gml:timePosition>
                </gml:TimeInstant>
            </iwxxm:issueTime>

            <iwxxm:originatingCentre>
                <iwxxm:WorldAreaForecastCentre>London</iwxxm:WorldAreaForecastCentre>
            </iwxxm:originatingCentre>

            <iwxxm:phenomenonCategory>weatherForecasts</iwxxm:phenomenonCategory>

            <iwxxm:phenomenonBaseTime>
                <gml:TimeInstant>
                    <gml:timePosition>
                        2024-03-13T06:00:00Z
                    </gml:timePosition>
                </gml:TimeInstant>
            </iwxxm:phenomenonBaseTime>

            <iwxxm:phenomenonTime>
                <gml:TimeInstant>
                    <gml:timePosition>
                        2024-03-13T12:00:00Z
                    </gml:timePosition>
                </gml:TimeInstant>
            </iwxxm:phenomenonTime>

        <iwxxm:feature>
    <iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature gml:id="uuid.a313b68c-2ca7-4f7d-8b7d-ad7057349c68">
        <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://wafs/sigwxobj">07f7d965-f3e8-464f-9787-37b3bcb0ed20</gml:identifier>
        <iwxxm:phenomenon xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/CLOUD"/>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
            <iwxxm:ElevatedVolume gml:id="uuid.d4ba7866-a67e-48ad-9acc-1b226ed3c31e" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                <gml:patches>
                    <gml:PolygonPatch>
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:Ring>
                                <gml:curveMember>
                                    <gml:Curve gml:id="uuid.d6b2d198-a467-4263-a04d-23749c2cec02" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                                        <gml:segments>
                                            <gml:CubicSpline>
                                                <gml:posList> -10.609801 44.262326 -9.962204 45.675180 -9.107841 46.971139 -9.200131 48.499959 -9.452731 50.031977 -9.050469 51.453669 -8.047463 50.535230 -6.885727 49.582419 -6.669162 48.093414 -6.172310 46.669747 -6.019344 45.159802 -6.415704 43.671523 -6.604483 42.144966 -7.989829 41.777905 -9.519369 41.920123 -10.660996 42.944946 -10.609801 44.262326 </gml:posList>
                                                <gml:vectorAtStart> 6.61293 23.92903 </gml:vectorAtStart>
                                                <gml:vectorAtEnd> 6.61293 23.92903 </gml:vectorAtEnd>
                                            </gml:CubicSpline>
                                        </gml:segments>
                                    </gml:Curve>
                                </gml:curveMember>
                            </gml:Ring>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:PolygonPatch>
                </gml:patches>
                <iwxxm:upperElevation uom="FL">470</iwxxm:upperElevation>
                <iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>MSL</iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>
                <iwxxm:lowerElevation uom="FL" xsi:nil="true" nilReason="http://codes.wmo.int/common/nil/inapplicable"/>
            </iwxxm:ElevatedVolume>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudDistribution xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-008/10"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudType xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-012/9"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
    </iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature>
</iwxxm:feature><iwxxm:feature>
    <iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature gml:id="uuid.76056d82-dd74-4945-8f42-0c1a70295c89">
        <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://wafs/sigwxobj">0f31894a-5e68-4b94-87fb-0b58e28b9714</gml:identifier>
        <iwxxm:phenomenon xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/CLOUD"/>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
            <iwxxm:ElevatedVolume gml:id="uuid.45181b98-d294-4060-8437-095060c8ff48" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                <gml:patches>
                    <gml:PolygonPatch>
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:Ring>
                                <gml:curveMember>
                                    <gml:Curve gml:id="uuid.b28eb469-a79a-46b5-9a0e-14e7e3bf38c2" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                                        <gml:segments>
                                            <gml:CubicSpline>
                                                <gml:posList> 41.687936 -43.795386 40.799641 -43.866458 40.041163 -43.340670 39.949882 -42.230097 40.410146 -41.235731 40.539176 -40.099938 40.435238 -38.956232 40.894967 -37.975267 41.616117 -37.283265 42.454254 -37.530298 42.752544 -38.620371 42.687632 -39.825311 42.640610 -41.034516 42.661304 -42.243776 42.488889 -43.382121 41.687936 -43.795386 </gml:posList>
                                                <gml:vectorAtStart> -16.53924 -4.44364 </gml:vectorAtStart>
                                                <gml:vectorAtEnd> -16.53924 -4.44364 </gml:vectorAtEnd>
                                            </gml:CubicSpline>
                                        </gml:segments>
                                    </gml:Curve>
                                </gml:curveMember>
                            </gml:Ring>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:PolygonPatch>
                </gml:patches>
                <iwxxm:upperElevation uom="FL">270</iwxxm:upperElevation>
                <iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>MSL</iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>
                <iwxxm:lowerElevation uom="FL" xsi:nil="true" nilReason="http://codes.wmo.int/common/nil/inapplicable"/>
            </iwxxm:ElevatedVolume>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudDistribution xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-008/10"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudType xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-012/9"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
    </iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature>
</iwxxm:feature><iwxxm:feature>
    <iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature gml:id="uuid.908f10f6-2c78-4b66-bf88-a5a9ae3b4e5e">
        <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://wafs/sigwxobj">174e6b3b-6792-4303-b581-7130a6abe0aa</gml:identifier>
        <iwxxm:phenomenon xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/CLOUD"/>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
            <iwxxm:ElevatedVolume gml:id="uuid.2ee613d8-7262-4562-92ee-033b6325065e" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                <gml:patches>
                    <gml:PolygonPatch>
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:Ring>
                                <gml:curveMember>
                                    <gml:Curve gml:id="uuid.c6a6efd9-d386-4262-be19-2277ec6a8268" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                                        <gml:segments>
                                            <gml:CubicSpline>
                                                <gml:posList> -5.552057 -42.468044 -6.423847 -42.404416 -7.299825 -42.417873 -7.998377 -41.845742 -8.375444 -41.029224 -8.492455 -40.134720 -7.959914 -39.434455 -7.122734 -39.100703 -6.274357 -39.285057 -5.532413 -39.793083 -4.803053 -40.324673 -4.188305 -40.980897 -4.068031 -41.837148 -4.684471 -42.474145 -5.552057 -42.468044 </gml:posList>
                                                <gml:vectorAtStart> -12.53193 1.94870 </gml:vectorAtStart>
                                                <gml:vectorAtEnd> -12.53193 1.94870 </gml:vectorAtEnd>
                                            </gml:CubicSpline>
                                        </gml:segments>
                                    </gml:Curve>
                                </gml:curveMember>
                            </gml:Ring>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:PolygonPatch>
                </gml:patches>
                <iwxxm:upperElevation uom="FL">420</iwxxm:upperElevation>
                <iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>MSL</iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>
                <iwxxm:lowerElevation uom="FL" xsi:nil="true" nilReason="http://codes.wmo.int/common/nil/inapplicable"/>
            </iwxxm:ElevatedVolume>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudDistribution xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-008/10"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudType xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-012/9"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
    </iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature>
</iwxxm:feature><iwxxm:feature>
    <iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature gml:id="uuid.ec91f9fa-b038-4654-b69e-6b9058d825e2">
        <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://wafs/sigwxobj">24f2d8f8-6a56-499f-9896-6d056d195833</gml:identifier>
        <iwxxm:phenomenon xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/CLOUD"/>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
            <iwxxm:ElevatedVolume gml:id="uuid.5ece1e92-09ed-403e-b0b7-647ec269d0b3" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                <gml:patches>
                    <gml:PolygonPatch>
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:Ring>
                                <gml:curveMember>
                                    <gml:Curve gml:id="uuid.19e0c542-889a-4c81-99db-03aba33a8737" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                                        <gml:segments>
                                            <gml:CubicSpline>
                                                <gml:posList> 3.252960 -167.264589 2.952292 -166.594695 2.758902 -165.885178 2.952823 -165.196135 3.591436 -164.866490 4.330688 -164.865214 4.984889 -165.163568 5.212041 -165.844369 5.060585 -166.565290 4.954874 -167.293432 4.454510 -167.808731 3.735134 -167.796084 3.252960 -167.264589 </gml:posList>
                                                <gml:vectorAtStart> -4.34028 7.80444 </gml:vectorAtStart>
                                                <gml:vectorAtEnd> -4.34028 7.80444 </gml:vectorAtEnd>
                                            </gml:CubicSpline>
                                        </gml:segments>
                                    </gml:Curve>
                                </gml:curveMember>
                            </gml:Ring>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:PolygonPatch>
                </gml:patches>
                <iwxxm:upperElevation uom="FL">440</iwxxm:upperElevation>
                <iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>MSL</iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>
                <iwxxm:lowerElevation uom="FL" xsi:nil="true" nilReason="http://codes.wmo.int/common/nil/inapplicable"/>
            </iwxxm:ElevatedVolume>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudDistribution xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-008/10"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudType xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-012/9"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
    </iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature>
</iwxxm:feature><iwxxm:feature>
    <iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature gml:id="uuid.540798d0-5306-4a5e-843c-ad21799a8f07">
        <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://wafs/sigwxobj">2559abfb-0eae-4452-a0bc-b4cc1adf24db</gml:identifier>
        <iwxxm:phenomenon xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/49-2/MeteorologicalFeature/CLOUD"/>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
            <iwxxm:ElevatedVolume gml:id="uuid.c82522d3-bdf4-4a7d-93ff-1ebecad848f3" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                <gml:patches>
                    <gml:PolygonPatch>
                        <gml:exterior>
                            <gml:Ring>
                                <gml:curveMember>
                                    <gml:Curve gml:id="uuid.3ea4fd8f-dfe7-4c78-9c18-1f35c00bd90f" srsDimension="2" axisLabels="Lat Long" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
                                        <gml:segments>
                                            <gml:CubicSpline>
                                                <gml:posList> -1.118413 4.962604 -2.002967 5.863330 -2.179289 7.139197 -2.152917 8.438727 -2.791197 9.547528 -3.902412 10.213778 -4.477394 11.351959 -4.567405 12.641191 -4.070717 13.843212 -2.946534 14.253081 -2.216566 13.226689 -1.456632 12.203315 -0.535192 11.301692 0.327613 10.346779 0.070907 9.105288 0.017334 7.819173 0.123501 6.533180 0.039003 5.266924 -1.118413 4.962604 </gml:posList>
                                                <gml:vectorAtStart> -23.27403 6.44304 </gml:vectorAtStart>
                                                <gml:vectorAtEnd> -23.27403 6.44304 </gml:vectorAtEnd>
                                            </gml:CubicSpline>
                                        </gml:segments>
                                    </gml:Curve>
                                </gml:curveMember>
                            </gml:Ring>
                        </gml:exterior>
                    </gml:PolygonPatch>
                </gml:patches>
                <iwxxm:upperElevation uom="FL">520</iwxxm:upperElevation>
                <iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>MSL</iwxxm:upperVerticalReference>
                <iwxxm:lowerElevation uom="FL" xsi:nil="true" nilReason="http://codes.wmo.int/common/nil/inapplicable"/>
            </iwxxm:ElevatedVolume>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonGeometry>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudDistribution xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-008/10"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
        <iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
            <iwxxm:CloudType xlink:href="http://codes.wmo.int/bufr4/codeflag/0-20-012/9"/>
        </iwxxm:phenomenonProperty>
    </iwxxm:MeteorologicalFeature>
</iwxxm:feature>
```

My goal is to have a GeoJSON file looking like:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "All Weather Features",
"features": [
   { 
      "type": "Feature", 
      "properties": { 
         "phenomenon": "Value from phenomenon", 
         "phenomenonProperty": "...",
         "upperElevation": ""
         "upperVerticalReference": ""
          ...
       }, 
      "geometry": Full geometry
   }
```